# Spring Boot won't load user-defined Dialect

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, cloud-foundry

I have an application that uses a custom self-defined dialect with Spring Boot JPA Hibernate.

The custom dialect looks like:

```
public class JsonPostgreSQL94Dialect extends PostgreSQL94Dialect {
   public JsonPostgreSQL94Dialect() {
      this.registerColumnType(Types.JAVA_OBJECT, "jsonb");
   }
}
```

This dialect extends the PostgreSQL dialect and adds support for the jsonb datatype.

Now, when I start my application, using Spring Boot, in certain environments it will NOT load the appropriate Dialect. I have tried defining the Dialect in the following ways:

In application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.test.util.JsonPostgreSQL94Dialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.test.util.JsonPostgreSQL94Dialect
```

Additionally I can define this in hibernate.properties:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.test.util.JsonPostgreSQL94Dialect
```

Here is the Spring Boot log of my application startup in Cloud Foundry using the Java Buildpack:

```
   2017-11-13T18:03:54.79+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/1] OUT 2017-11-13 18:03:54.792  INFO 19 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

The startup will NOT recognize my defined Dialect. It defaults to the normal PostgreSQL dialect which causes my application to fail on the unrecognized data type.

Is there something within Spring Boot that is overriding my definition for the Dialect? Is there a more proper way to define the dialect?

Comment: Have you tried `--debug` or `debug=true` in `application.properties`?  It's supposed to output more info about Hibernate (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-console-output).  Also, it will output some more info regarding Spring Boot's auto configurations.  That would show you more details about what automatic configuration is running in your app.

Comment: Also, if it works locally but not in Cloud Foundry check to see if your app has any conditional configuration by using profiles, in particular, the "cloud" profile.  When you deploy to Cloud Foundry, the Java buildpack will automatically enable the "cloud" profile which can alter the way your app is configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that [Spring Auto-Reconfiguration](https://spring.io/blog/2011/11/04/using-cloud-foundry-services-with-spring-part-2-auto-reconfiguration/) was kicking in when the project deployed to our Cloud Foundry environment. The Auto-Reconfiguration Bean was active and was responsible for changing the Dialect of my application. This was due to the VCAP Services for my Database (PostgreSQL) being detected by the bean and then being auto-configured.

My solution was to turn off the Auto-Reconfiguration Bean by adding the following environment variable to my application manifest:

```
JBP_CONFIG_SPRING_AUTO_RECONFIGURATION: '{enabled: false}'
```

With the Auto-Reconfiguration disabled, my dialect was no longer being overridden by Spring.